# German for “contiguous simplicial maps”

Tags: algebraic-topology, translation-request, mathematical-german

Is there an established German word for “contiguous” in the sense of contiguous simplicial maps?

---

**Background**

*Definition.* Two simplicial maps $f$ and $g$ from $\mathcal K$ to $\mathcal L$ are called contiguous, if whenever $S$ is the set of vertices of a simplex of $\mathcal K$ the set $f[S]\cup g[S]$ is the set of vertices of a simplex of $\mathcal L$.

I am teaching a class in German, and I will go with „benachbart“, if no-one knows a better word. I would look if the concept is used in Seifert and Threlfall, but I do not have it at hand.

Comment: I would use "angrenzend" which results from the German noun "Grenze" for border. It means that they share the same border.

Comment: wait a minute - did I refer to your paper?

Comment: @FWE, those were most likely the lecture notes that I was preparing when I asked the question. Thanks, that made my day ;)

Comment: And I see that the notes remained incomplete. Tsk.

Answer (score 2):

The German term "benachbart" seems appropriate - see e.g.

(1) 15.3 in [Carsten Schultz' Seiten](https://carsten.codimi.de/at1314/at1314-15.pdf)

(2) p. 31 in [Eberhard Schock.Konvergente Iterationsverfahren für flach konvexe Banachräume](https://books.google.de/books?id=JXydBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=benachbart%20simpliziale%20abbildungen&source=bl&ots=oau3HPegqx&sig=ACfU3U2MWObDamo1SZXhbGX8m-wTjB4GxQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL9puF0__gAhWRkxQKHT8EBOcQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=benachbart%20simpliziale%20abbildungen&f=false)

For the second I am not sure if the meaning is identical to yours though.

Comment: As noted in the comments to the question, the first reference is not that helpful in this context, but the second one is, thanks.